# NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' error when creating pandas dataframe from Dict

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

Im trying to create a pandas dataframe from a dictionary and I keep getting the error: NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys' and have no clue how to solve this. Below is my code and some test data for testing. Im sure its something stupid im missing.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def grab_next_entry(food_file):
    record={'id':-1,'helpfulness':'','number rated':'','score':'','review':''}
    line=food_file.readline()


    #food_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)

    while line:
        if 'product/productId' in line:
            split_product_id=line.split(':')
            record['id']=split_product_id[1]

        if 'review/helpfulness' in line:
            split_helpfulness=line.split(':')
            split_helpfulness=split_helpfulness[1].split('/')
            record['helpfulness']=eval(split_helpfulness[0])
            record['number rated']=eval(split_helpfulness[-1])

        if 'review/score' in line:
            split_score = line.split(':')
            record['score']=eval(split_score[1])

        if 'review/text' in line:
            split_review_text=line.split('review/text:')
            record['review']=split_review_text[1:]

        if line=='\n':
            return record
        line=food_file.readline()
```

End of first section of code
Calling code:

```
import os

fileLoc = "/Users/brawdyll/Documents/ds710fall2017assignment11/finefoods_test.txt"
column_names=('Product ID', 'People who voted Helpful','Total votes','Rating','Review')
food_dataframe=[]
data=[]
with open(fileLoc,encoding = "ISO 8859-1") as food_file:
    fs=os.fstat(food_file.fileno()).st_size
    num_read = 0
    while not food_file.tell()==fs:
        data.append(grab_next_entry(food_file))
        num_read+=1
    food_dataframe=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(food_dataframe)
```

Test Input

```
product/productId: B001E4KFG0
review/userId: A3SGXH7AUHU8GW
review/profileName: delmartian
review/helpfulness: 1/1
review/score: 5.0
review/time: 1303862400
review/summary: Good Quality Dog Food
review/text: I have bought several of the Vitality canned dog food products and have found them all to be of good quality. The product looks more like a stew than a processed meat and it smells better. My Labrador is finicky and she appreciates this product better than  most.

product/productId: B00813GRG4
review/userId: A1D87F6ZCVE5NK
review/profileName: dll pa
review/helpfulness: 0/0
review/score: 1.0
review/time: 1346976000
review/summary: Not as Advertised
review/text: Product arrived labeled as Jumbo Salted Peanuts...the peanuts were actually small sized unsalted. Not sure if this was an error or if the vendor intended to represent the product as "Jumbo".
```

Comment: If the last line in the file is not a blank line, you don't return anything, and therefore return `None`.

Comment: I can not find keyword 'keys' in your code. Where is it?

Comment: Add a `\n` (**exactly** one) at the end of your input file. Note: *Python* has a way of iterating through lines in a file, mixing that with `tell` is not a good idea. You could also test the result of `grab_next_entry` before appending it to `data`.